# same 'num' but different value

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to Oracle's SQL and need help. How can I select only those rows that have the same 'code' for a different 'name'?

For example I have Table 1 and I want to get Table 2.

Table 1: customer

| id | name | num_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jenny | 456 |
| 2 | Jenny | 456 |
| 3 | Ben | 456 |
| 4 | Ursula | 879 |
| 5 | Mike | 145 |
| 6 | Mike | 145 |
| 7 | Nick | 954 |

Table 2: customer

| id | name | num_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jenny | 456 |
| 3 | Ben | 456 |

This is my query:

```
select distinct t1.name, t1.num_id
  from customer t1
  join (select distinct name, num_id, count(*)
          from customer
         group by name, num_id
        having count(*) > 1) t2
    on t1.num_id = t2.num_id
   and t1.name <> t2.name
 order by 2;
```

But it does not work.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for the name in the subquery. You need to find `num_id` which has multiple names, therefore `group by num_id` and `count(distinct name)`.

```
select distinct t1.name, t1.num_id
from customer t1
    join (
        select num_id, count (distinct name)
        from customer
        group by num_id
        having count (distinct name) > 1 
) t2 on t1.num_id = t2.num_id
order by 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below sql to get the job done.

- First, in the inline view t, I use count analytic function to make oracle count distinct values per num_id.
- Then, I filter out the result from the inline t with cnt > 1 condition
- Then, I use group by clause to aggregate the result from the inline t per name and num_id columns. Once that, you just need to use min aggregate function to select the minimum id.

```sql
select min(id) id, name, num_id
from (
    select id, name, num_id, count(distinct name) over (partition by num_id) cnt
    from Your_Customer_Table
) t
where cnt > 1
group by name, num_id
order by 1
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2ddd4cd09bab73b5cf30a591b1b89a7d)